# Selecting second largest length of a field in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using the following query to return the length of the longest value for Field1:

```
SELECT MAX(LEN(Field1))
FROM Table1
```

How can I modify my query to return second largest length for Field1?

Comment: check out [this](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/database-sql/find-nth-highest-salary-sql/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the inner query, you can select the maximum length of the column and eliminate it in the outer query and do a `max` so you get the second largest length in that column.

```
select max(val) as secondlargest
from t join
(
SELECT max(len(val)) as lf1
FROM t
) x
on len(t.val) < x.lf1
```

If you need all the values with the second largest length, it is best to use `cte`s. [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/af18a/16)

```
with top2 as (
select top 2 len(val) as lf1
from t
order by len(val) desc
) ,
scnd as 
(select min(lf1) as snd from top2)
select val
from t join scnd 
on len(t.val) = scnd.snd
```

Comment: vkp, max(val) does not deal with length. It should be max(len(val)) shouldn't it?

Comment: @ElenaDBA..in the first query, you would only get one `val` for the second maximum length. However, the second query using `cte` gives you all the values with the second maximum length.

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server 2012+ supports `OFFSET/FETCH`:

```
select len(f1)
from table1
group by len(f1)
order by len(f1) desc
offset 1
fetch first 1 row only;
```

In earlier versions there are various methods.  Here is one:

```
with ml as (
      select len(f1) as lenf
      from table1
      group by len(f1)
     )
select max(lenf)
from ml
where lenf < (select max(lenf) from ml);
```

Comment: Then presumably you are using an earlier version of SQL Server.

Comment: I am using Azure SQL and accessing it via Management Studio 2014

Comment: @ElenaDBA . . . I suspect that SQL Server *requires* the `ORDER BY`.  In the documentation, the `OFFSET`/`FETCH` clauses are part of the `ORDER BY` clause (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx) . . . and available in SQL Azure.

Answer (score 1):

**Window Functions** are usually the most efficient way to do this, and they are ultimately flexible to fit varying requirements. Here is an example (tested on Azure SQL DB):

```
select f1, lenf, lenf_dense_rank
from (
        SELECT 
            f1, 
            lenf=len(f1), 
            lenf_dense_rank=dense_rank() over (order by len(f1) desc)
        FROM table1
) x
where lenf_dense_rank = 2
```

Again, depending on your needs, you may want to use `rank()` versus `dense_rank()`, but **Window Functions** are still the technique to use for situations like this.  Highly suggest looking them up and learning more about them - they should be used way more often than they currently are.

Comment: BTW, by saying "usually more efficient", I mean that you're doing exactly 1 full table scan (or index scan), whereas self-joins, and using max combined with a subquery on the same table requires at least 2 of the same type of scan - the relative amount of work done by the DBMS should not be ignored!  Using the OFFSET/FETCH combo does effectively the same thing, but Window Functions can do so much more, and are now so widely supported, that I have to recommend them wherever possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the second one:

```
SELECT MAX(Field1) FROM Table1
WHERE Field1 NOT IN (SELECT MAX(Field1) FROM Table1)
```

Do note that this is only correct when the two maximum values are not the same. If they are, the second answer will still be selected. For example:

```
1: 500 points
2: 500 points
3: 410 points
```

2 will still be selected, but it's debatable which answer you need.